# How to instantiate react component with injected properties

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mobx, mobx-react

I'm converting a react project from redux to mobx, and I'm having the following problem: I was using the container/presenter pattern with redux, which meant using the redux "connect" function, like this:

```
 export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Leads);
```

The problem I'm having is that there's no equivalent mobx function, so instead, I tried to simply create an instance of the component in the container. Something like:

```
render() {
  return (
    <MyComponent
      store={mystore}
    />
  );
}
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't work, because MyComponent has injected properties from react-router, something like this:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component<ReportProps & RouteComponentProps<ReportProps>> {

  constructor(public routeProps: ReportProps & RouteComponentProps<ReportProps>) {
    super(routeProps);
  }...
```

I tried getting rid of the container concept, but the same problem occurs in other places because I'm using the mobx-react @inject decorator. For example, I have a component like this:

```
export interface AddressProps {
  report: IReportStore;
}

@inject((rootStore: RootStore) => ({
  report: rootStore.report
}))
@observer
class Address extends React.Component<AddressProps> {
...
```

If I then try to use my component somewhere, typescript complains that I'm not passing the required property (report, in this instance), even though I shouldn't need to, since I'm injecting the properties.

I figure I must be missing something basic, as this is a fairly straightforward use of mobx. Or maybe it's just a typescript problem...? If so, any ideas how to fix or work around it?

Thanks in advance,
Jonathan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of problems around the mobx inject method.

the original idea was to return a `Partial<TProps>` but you can't do this typed without losing your original Class: `React.Component<Partial<TProps>,TState>` != `YourComponent` - the set properties.

Read the discussed problem here: https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react/issues/256

### Simplistic solution

Use optional parameters in props and set them in a getter property:

```
interface AppProps {
    store?: SDtore;
}

class App {
  get store(): TimeEntryStore {
    return this.props.store as Store;
  }
  method(){
     this.store;///
  }
}
```

### Other solution

If you want to keep your required parameters (eg: for using the component outside of mobx etc).

You can consider casting the component to `React.Component<TPropsReduced,State>` where TPropsReduced is a self defined interface with required props after injected.

The downsides are:

- Losing type safety at casting (eg if you make mistakes/typo's in the interface properties. (can be solved by extending/subclassing interfaces.
- Losing methods calls. You will no longer have typed methods on the component (eg: when you use `ref={()=>}`), but using this is dis-advised anyways.

Example:

```
interface AddressPropsMobx {
}

interface AddressProps extends AddressPropsMobx {
  report: IReportStore;
}



//Pure react component
class Address extends React.Component<AddressProps> {}

// Mobx version:
const MobxAddress = inject((rootStore: RootStore) => ({
  report: rootStore.report
}))(observer(Address)) as React.Component<AddressPropsMobx>;  //unsafe cast
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I solved my problem using one of the many solutions proposed on the github issue page you linked to: I've now got a utility function called typedInject which I wrap around my component before exporting it, and it works perfectly. Simply making the properties optional is too much hassle, because you then need to check whether it's defined every time you try to use it...